# How to filter Outlook for Mac calendar events by category using AppleScript

Tags: macos, calendar, outlook, applescript

I'm trying to write an Applescript on OSX to filter Outlook for Mac 2011 calendar events based on event categories, e.g. find all events tagged as "Conference". For example, I have a calendar event named "WWDC" that is found by the following script:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
  set theCategoryConference to first category whose name is "Conference"
  set theConferenceList to every calendar event whose (subject is "WWDC")
  display dialog "There were " & (count of theConferenceList) & " Conferences."
  set theEvent to item 1 of items of theConferenceList
  display dialog "Categories contains conference: " & (categories of theEvent contains {theCategoryConference})
end tell
```

The above finds 1 event, and the final line displays "true" as this event has been tagged with the Conference category.

However what I really want to do is find all such events. The following fails to match any events:

```
set theConferenceList to every calendar event whose categories contains {theCategoryConference}
```

Is there a different syntax to use, or is this a limitation of Outlook for Mac that perhaps doesn't allow filtering events based on a nested collection (the `categories` attribute on `calendar event` objects)?

Answer (score 0):

See [Search Outlook contacts by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859148/search-outlook-contacts-by-category)

Here we use the spotlight/`mdfind`/`mdls` workaround to find all the relevant categorized events.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set theCategoryConference to first category whose name is "Conference"
    set theConferenceList to every calendar event whose (subject is "WWDC")
    display dialog "There were " & (count of theConferenceList) & " Conferences."
    set theEvent to item 1 of items of theConferenceList
    display dialog "Categories contains conference: " & (categories of theEvent contains {theCategoryConference})
    --set theConferenceList to every calendar event whose categories contains {theCategoryConference}

    set currentIdentityFolder to quoted form of POSIX path of (current identity folder as string)
    set cmd to "mdfind -onlyin " & currentIdentityFolder & "  'kMDItemContentType == com.microsoft.outlook14.event && com_microsoft_outlook_categories == " & id of theCategoryConference & "' | xargs -I % mdls -name com_microsoft_outlook_recordID '%' | cut -d'=' -f2 | sort -u | paste -s -"
    set theEventIDs to words of (do shell script cmd)

    set theConferenceList to {}
    repeat with thisEventID in theEventIDs
        set end of theConferenceList to calendar event id thisEventID
    end repeat

    -- For example display the subject of the first event
    display dialog subject of (item 1 of theConferenceList) as string
end tell
```