# AppleScript - How to change category of calendar event based on subject of calendar event

Tags: events, calendar, outlook, applescript, categories

I'm using Outlook 2011 for Mac.

The idea is to label all *calendar events with "X123" as subject* with a new category: *category "Blabla"*. With this change, I also want to delete the old category, if there is one.

I got a little snippet from [Ramon's topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387825/how-to-filter-outlook-for-mac-calendar-events-by-category-using-applescript) (thanks!), but could someone help me out, since the question is a bit different.

This is what I got till now:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set theCategory to first category whose name is "Blabla"
    set theEventList to every calendar event whose (subject is "X123")
    display dialog "There are " & (count of theEventList) & " Events."
    set theEvent to item 1 of items of theEventList

    set currentIdentityFolder to quoted form of POSIX path of (current identity folder as string)
    set cmd to "mdfind -onlyin " & currentIdentityFolder & "  'kMDItemContentType == com.microsoft.outlook14.event && com_microsoft_outlook_categories == " & id of theCategory & "' | xargs -I % mdls -name com_microsoft_outlook_recordID '%' | cut -d'=' -f2 | sort -u | paste -s -"
    set theEventIDs to words of (do shell script cmd)

    set theCategory to {}
    repeat with thisEventID in theEventIDs
        -- set the new category
        set theCategory to category "Blabla"
        display dialog "test"
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: The first paragraph stores the category "Blabla" inside `theCategory`, all events with subject "X123" in `theEventList` and the first event with subject "X123" in `theEvent`. The second paragraph stores all events with the category "Blabla". The third paragraph walks through `theEventIDs` and overwrites `theCategory` with the category "Blabla" and displays "test" **each time**!

What do you want to do with `theEventList` from the first paragraph? Inside the third paragraph you maybe want to `set the category of calendar event id thisEventID to theCategory` and how does this fit your question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ShooTerKo. I've got some help from a genius. This piece of AppleScript is the answer of my own question:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set theCategory to category "Blabla" -- theCategory = "Blabla"
    set theEventList to every calendar event whose subject contains "X123" -- theEventList contains "X123"

    -- Loop through each event
    repeat with theEvent in theEventList
        set category of theEvent to {} -- Empty all other categories
        set category of theEvent to {theCategory} -- Set the new category to theCategory
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set theCategory to category "iOGS" -- theCategory = "Blabla"
    set theEventList to every calendar event whose organizer contains "@yourdomain.com" -- theEventList contains "X123"
    
    -- Loop through each event
    repeat with theEvent in theEventList
        set category of theEvent to {} -- Empty all other categories
        set category of theEvent to {theCategory} -- Set the new category to theCategory
    end repeat
end tell
```

The above code uses the [previous, excellent code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26715542/10871073) as a basis and modifies it to set the category based on the organizer's email domain.